# How to read Promise resolved value from a function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 functions in total, one function that is returning a new Promise and resolving to a variable, like so:

```
  function promiseTest(data) {
    const delay = 200;
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(data), delay));
  }
```

and then another function where I'm calling this function, and then inserting for the `data` variable a JSON object.

```
    function getInfo() {
     return promiseTest(require('./allData.json'));
    }
```

So my question is, how do I read the data that the Promise is resolving from the `getInfo` function, just in a simple console.log?

Say: `console.log(getInfo().data)` (but obviously this doesn't work but hopefully helps with what I'm after).

Comment: You can't just magically make an asynchronous operation synchronous. Use async/await, pass callbacks or use .then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With promises you have to use/extract the data using a .then(); so

```
getInfo().then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Is there a particular reason why you need to use a promise? Your example seems suited to simply using the setTimeout function

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this.

## Async/await

JavaScript introduced the `async` and `await` keywords a few years ago. It's a special syntax simplifying asynchronous programming. You can make your functions `async`, and use `await` when calling them. It basically wraps the whole `. then()` mess.

```js
async function promiseTest(data) {
    const delay = 200;
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(data), delay));
}


async function getInfo() {
    return await promiseTest(require('./allData.json'));
}
```

Then, you can then get `getInfo()`'s result by awaiting it:

```js
console.log(await getInfo());
```

Here are some reading which should help you:

https://javascript.info/async-await
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/async_function

## .then()

You can also go with the old way, using then:

```js
function promiseTest(data) {
    const delay = 200;
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(data), delay));
}


function getInfo() {
    return promiseTest(require('./allData.json'));
}

getInfo().then(data => console.log(data));
```

## Pass a callback

You could pass a callback to your getInfo method.

```js
function promiseTest(data) {
    const delay = 200;
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(data), delay));
}


function getInfo(callback) {
    promiseTest(require('./allData.json')).then(data => callback(data));
}

getInfo(data => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

The value that the promise returns is passed as the first parameter into the `.then` function.

Please see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

In your case that could be:
getInfo().then(data => console.log(data));

Hope this helps.